# Graph theory: maximun edge count given a specific degree

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any theorem that calculates the maximum number of edges given a specific degree? Or, what topology would a graph of certain average degree should have so that the edge count is maximum?

I know the reverse, to count the edges given the number of vertices and the degree. How about the number of vertices and edges given only the degree.

I need to find what the topology should be within the two-hop neighborhood of a node given the degree of all nodes included. My assumption is a tree... but is that correct? How can I prove it?

Thanks,
-- George

Comment: Not sure what are you asking about. Have you seen the [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma): $2\cdot |E| = \sum_{v \in V} \deg(v)$?

Comment: There is no maximum number of edges or vertices for _any_ given degree. Empty graphs, ladder rung graphs, cycle graphs, prism graphs and antiprism graphs are scaleable examples for degrees 0 to 4 respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let's assume we have x nodes and we want to connect them in such a way that each one of them has exactly d edges. What is the graph we will get? Is it a tree or can be other things as well?